# How to return the output of an awk statement as a JSON object?

Tags: json, node.js, awk

I am trying to run a shell script through Node JS. I am using child_process and spawn to execute the shell script.

**Server.js**

```
var deploysh = spawn('sh', [ 'VO.sh']);
```

The shell script has an awk script which reads a file and tries to find some data.

**VO.sh**

```
file='/home/sivasubr/node-project/VO.txt'
awk -F":" '{ 
  a[$1]+=$2
  count[$1]++
  if(max[$1] <  $2) max[$1]=$2
  if(min[$1]==NULL) min[$1]=$2
  if(min[$1] >  $2) min[$1]=$2
}

END{ 
  for(i in a)
    print i, a[i]/count[i], max[i], min[i]
}' $file
```

The awk statement returns something like the following:

```
VO1: 15 10 5
VO2: 10 5 2
```

I need the output of this awk statement to be made into a JSON object so that I can represent the data as a graph/chart. How do I go about it?

Comment: Please provide some example input and expected output

Comment: Modify the END section to print out whatever format you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't emit a colon you could parse the below text with `jq`:

```
VO1 15 10 5
VO2 10 5 2
```

Command:

```bash
... awk ... | head -c-1 | 
jq '. | split("\n") | map( split(" ") | { label: .[0], avg: .[1], max: .[2], min: .[3] } )' -Rs
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "label": "VO1",
    "avg": "15",
    "max": "10",
    "min": "5"
  },
  {
    "label": "VO2",
    "avg": "10",
    "max": "5",
    "min": "2"
  }
]
```